# Open Safari with URL from command line and get process handle

Tags: macos, process, safari

I know there are several ways in MacOS to open Safari with a given URL from the command line like

```
open -a Safari http://stackoverflow.com
```

Or as an AppleScript

```
tell application "Safari" to open location "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

But if I am starting the process e.g. programmatically I will only get the handle to the open/applescript process (which exits right after Safari is started).

How can I start Safari with a given URL and get the handle to the Safari process (it is still beyond me why it can't just pass the URL as a command line argument to the Safari executable)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in AppleScript, after opening Safari with URL

```
tell application "Safari" to open location "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

you may obtain the process object by

```
tell application "System Events" to set proc to application process "Safari"
```

the proc object will have pid, bundle id and etc attached to it.

Also please note that Safari 5+ runs in a [multi-process architecture](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKit2): a master process and several rendering process, the above code will get you the master process only; rendering processes are not easily accessible, nor does it make much sense to control any individual rendering process.

Comment: The second part of this is not brining Safari to the foreground. Is that possible?