# winopen for mac on matlab

Tags: macos, matlab, interop

is there a way to use `winopen` or a similar function on matlab 2010a for mac? 
I'm trying to open a html file on the standard browser.

```
winopen('myFile.html')
```

works fine on windows using different matlab versions, but not on mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
system(['open myFile.html']);
```

From http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25080-macopen

..or

```
system(['open -a Safari myFile.html']);
```

from [Open Safari with URL from command line and get process handle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12150569/708221)

Comment: This does not work for avi, for instance. There is a simple script `macopen` in Mathworks which works similarly to winopen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unix('open myFile.html')
```