# How do I write a script to open Safari with multiple specified website tabs open?

Tags: bash, shell, web, safari, automation

Searching so far, all I've found is [open -a safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150569/open-safari-with-url-from-command-line-and-get-process-handle). I will keep searching trying to teach myself, but I would appreciate your guidance to direct my efforts.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the URLs as parameters to that command:

```
open -a safari 'https://stackoverflow.com' 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391547'
```

This will open Safari with two tabs, one for each URL.